# Plugin for changing urls of one type to another automatically

Tags: javascript, url, firefox, plugins

I have a set of internal university links of the form http://www.foo.in/x/* and they only work if changed manually to http://www.foo.in/x/y/*

Is there any plugin that will help me automatically change all links of the first type to the second when I click on them? If not, is there a way to write such a plugin?

I use firefox/chrome on linux.

I have never written any plugin before, and have heard of java script but never written any.

I would be grateful for any links in this direction.
Thanks

Comment: Some plugin for simple search and substitute within a url. I googled for it, but couldn't find such a plugin

Comment: handle it at the server.. rewrite url.. what is your users dont install  this plugin

Comment: I *am* the user. I don't have access to the server. The links at the server are broken. I just want my browser to automatically change all hyperlinks of the first type to the second, when I click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... simple jQuery code to replace all links on document ready, but only whith specific class.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.foo.in/x/foo.html" class="link">Link one</a>
<a href="http://www.foo.in/x/bar.html" class="link">Link two</a>
<a href="http://www.foo.in/x/bar.html">Link tree (not affected)</a>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').each(function() {
        var newLink = $(this).attr('href');
        newLink = newLink.replace("/x", "/x/y");
        $(this).attr('href',newLink);
    });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bFWR7/)

---

**EDITED** to match with new information:

Create a new bookmark in your browser (crtl+D in chrome) and edit the bookmark url.
Replace the url with this code:

```
javascript:function getLinks(){var arr=new Array();arr=document.getElementsByTagName("a");for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){var link=document.getElementsByTagName("a").item(i).href;newLink=link.replace("/x","/x/y");document.getElementsByTagName('a').item(i).href=newLink;}};getLinks();
```

Don't miss the initial "*javascrip:*"

Now, when you are in the page you want to replace the links, just click on the bookmark and the links will be replaced.

Comment: You have to insert the script in the head of your file. If you can paste an html example I can modify for you to tell you where.

Comment: I am just a user. I don't have access to the server. If I did I would just go and correct all the broken links once in for all.

Comment: Ok, so you  need to create a script in Javascript and run like a bookmark., give me a few minutes and I can give you an example.